# Terminal sort command options: sort -k1,1

Tags: sort

```
cat input.txt | sort -k1,1
```

I am trying to figure out what the `,1` part at the end does in this command. `input.txt` is a 2 column file. First column is some word and second column is the number 1. `-k1` tells it to sort by the first column, so alphabetically in this case. What does the second part, `,1` do?

Comment: `man sort` and look for the `-k` flag... and then search further down for the `KEYDEF` that it refers to.

Comment: I did, but I didn't quite understand where the comma part came in when I `man`'ed it.

Comment: Please can I suggest next time you mention that. It's good to show you've tried to solve something first, and you're less likely to get downvoted for "This question does not show any research effort."

Comment: Using GNU sort, the `--debug` option is nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-k1,1` in the command

```
sort -k1,1 input.txt
```

would sort on the data using the first column as the sorting key, only.  The first `1` denotes the start of the sorting key as column 1, and the second `1` denotes the same column as the end of the sorting key.  Had you used `-k1` or `-k1,2` on a file with two columns, then both columns would have been used (as would have been the case if `-k` was not used on the command line at all).

In short, the two digits refer to the sorting key's start and end column.

So, using `-k1,1` will only use the first of your two columns as the sorting key.  When two rows have *the same* key, however, the whole line will be used to determine the order of the two lines (unless another `-k` option is specified after the first, in which case that will be used before the whole line is used).

Comment: Sorry, I think I don't understand what you mean by the "start" and "end" of the sorting key. So say my first row is is word `tall 2` So the sorting key is `tall`. Are the letters `t` and `l` the start and end of the sorting key respectively, if the flag `-k1,1` is used?  Is the letter and number `t` and `l` the start and end of the sorting key, respectively, if the flag `-k1,2` is used?

Comment: oh I think your update answers this question

Comment: @Iamanon With `-k1,1`, the word `tall` would be used as the key to sort on. With `-k1` or `-k1,2`, the string `tall 2` would be used.  With `-k2` on your data, `2` would be used as the key.

Comment: @Iamanon To use only the filst two characters of the first column, you would use `-k1.1,1.2` I believe.

Comment: Ahh. Would the sorting key be `2 tall` if you used `-k2,1`?

Comment: @Iamanon I don't think you would be able to do that. Would you want to sort on the second column first, then on the first, I would use `-k2,2 -k1,1`, or possibly `-k2,2n -k1,1` since the second column is numeric.